# Getting an object from a JSON using JSONPath

Tags: jsonpath

I have a problem trying to get extract an object from a JSON using JSONpath. Example of the JSON:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "aa44v2",
    "detail-type": "v2.detail.events.conversation.{id}.attributes",
    "source": "aws.partner/xyz.com/cloud/aa44vv/GCSC",
    "account": "123444545",
    "time": "2023-02-01T08:21:11Z",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "topicName": "v2.detail.events.conversation.aa44vv.attributes",
        "version": "2",
        "eventBody": {
            "eventTime": 1675239671240,
            "conversationId": "aa44vv",
            "participantId": "aa44vb",
            "attributes": {
                "Custom2": "b",
                "Custom1": "a"
            }
        },
        "metadata": {
            "CorrelationId": "aa44vr"
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-02-01T08:21:11.240Z"
    }
}
```

I want to extract the whole "attributes" object, not the values contained on it (because I don't know beforehand the content, they are arbitrary key-value pairs)

I'm only capable of getting an array (through $.detail.eventBody.attributes or $..attributes), but I need the object. Is there any way of doing so?

[Screenshot from jsonpath.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkTcX.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will always get array of results, like when you checking RegExp with `g` flag.

You can receive object `attributes` using [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)/[underscore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore):

```js
const data = {
    "version": "0",
    "id": "aa44v2",
    "detail-type": "v2.detail.events.conversation.{id}.attributes",
    "source": "aws.partner/xyz.com/cloud/aa44vv/GCSC",
    "account": "123444545",
    "time": "2023-02-01T08:21:11Z",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "topicName": "v2.detail.events.conversation.aa44vv.attributes",
        "version": "2",
        "eventBody": {
            "eventTime": 1675239671240,
            "conversationId": "aa44vv",
            "participantId": "aa44vb",
            "attributes": {
                "Custom2": "b",
                "Custom1": "a"
            }
        },
        "metadata": {
            "CorrelationId": "aa44vr"
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-02-01T08:21:11.240Z"
    }
}

let results = jsonpath.query(data, '$.detail.eventBody.attributes');

console.log(_.first(results));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonpath@1.1.1/jsonpath.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Possibly, in case you have array in path, You can receive multiple objects in resulted array. So you can merge all resulted objects using lodash (underscore doesn't have that method):

```js
const data = {
    "version": "0",
    "id": "aa44v2",
    "detail-type": "v2.detail.events.conversation.{id}.attributes",
    "source": "aws.partner/xyz.com/cloud/aa44vv/GCSC",
    "account": "123444545",
    "time": "2023-02-01T08:21:11Z",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": [{
        "topicName": "v2.detail.events.conversation.aa44vv.attributes",
        "version": "2",
        "eventBody": {
            "eventTime": 1675239671240,
            "conversationId": "aa44vv",
            "participantId": "aa44vb",
            "attributes": {
                "Custom2": "b",
                "Custom1": "a"
            }
        },
        "metadata": {
            "CorrelationId": "aa44vr"
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-02-01T08:21:11.240Z"
    },
    {
        "topicName": "v2.detail.events.conversation.aa44vv.attributes",
        "version": "2",
        "eventBody": {
            "eventTime": 1675239671240,
            "conversationId": "aa44vv",
            "participantId": "aa44vb",
            "attributes": {
                "Custom3": "c",
                "Custom4": "d"
            }
        },
        "metadata": {
            "CorrelationId": "aa44vr"
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-02-01T08:21:11.240Z"
    }]
}

let results = jsonpath.query(data, '$.detail.*.eventBody.attributes');

console.log(_.merge(...results));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonpath@1.1.1/jsonpath.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```